# How do I use the Plesk Scheduler to call an Mvc page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, plesk

I want to send sms in every day in time 8:00.

I add a controller for send sms.

```
 public ActionResult ScheduleTask()
 {
   var sms = new com.aradsmsserver.www.Send();
   long[] rec = null;
   byte[] status = null;
   int retval = sms.SendSms("user", "pass", new string[] { "09130000000"}, "1000", "تست", false, "", ref rec, ref status);
  }
```

and add a vbs file.

```
Call ScheduleTask() 

Sub ScheduleTask()
On Error Resume Next

Dim objRequest
Dim URL

Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
URL = "http://mysite.ir/Schedule/ScheduleTask"

objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

objRequest.Send

Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

and in Plesk, add a `Scheduled Tasks`.

```
Specify the following in the "Path to executable file" input box

C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe

Specify the file name of your VB script in the “Arguments Field:

C:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.ir\httpdocs\schedule.vbs
```

But don't run This.

Comment: Does it work if you just open that page in your browser? If it doesn't it's because of the MVC web app. If not it's because of the VB script.

Comment: Yes, it is run when open page in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem.

path of schedule.vbs is in E:\

I use `E:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.ir\httpdocs\schedule.vbs` for `Arguments Field`.